# Laravel 8 [Yajra DataTable] - DataTables warning: table id=userTable - Invalid JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, yajra-datatable

I am trying to display all User (Where status is = 1) Data from database into DataTable using Yajra Package in Laravel but it always displays this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=userTrashBin - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

When I check the response **(In Developer's tools > Network Tab)** it does not have any or it show `Failed to load response data`:

[image]

Here's my **datatable()** inside the `UserController.php`:

```
public function datatable()
{
    $data = User::where('status', '=', 1)->get();
    
    return DataTables::of($data)
        ->addColumn('action', function($data){

        $url_edit = url('user/'.$data->id.'/edit');
        $url_deact = url('user/deactivateUser/'.$data->id);
        $url = url('user/'.$data->id);
        
        $view = "<a class = 'btn btn-primary' href = '".$url."' title = 'View'><i class = 'nav icon fas fa-eye'></i></a>";
        $edit = "<a class = 'btn btn-warning' href = '".$url_edit."' title = 'Edit'><i class = 'nav icon fas fa-edit'></i></a>";
        $delete = "<button data-url = '".$url_deact."' onclick = 'deleteData(this)' class = 'btn btn-action btn-danger' title = 'Deactivate'><i class = 'nav-icon fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button>";
        
        return $view."".$edit."".$delete; 
    })->editColumn('user_type', function($data){

        $dataUser = User::find($data->id)->first();
        $returnStr = "";

        if($dataUser->hasRole('A')){
            $returnStr = "Administrator";
        }else{
            $returnStr = "Employee";
        }

        return $returnStr;
    })
    ->rawColumns(['action'])
    ->make(true);
}
```

Here's the **script** file in `index.blade.php`:

```
$("#userTable").DataTable({
      responsive:true,
      processing:true,
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      stateSave:false,
      scrollY:true,
      scrollX:true,
      autoWidth: false,
      ajax:"{{ url('user/datatable') }}",
      columns:[
        {data:'first_name', name: 'first_name'},
        {data:'last_name', name: 'last_name'},
        {data:'email', name: 'email'},
        {data:'user_type', name: 'user_type'},
        {data:'action', name: 'action', searchable: true, sortable:true},
      ]
    });
```

The **route** for `user/datatable` inside `web.php`:

```
Route::get('user/datatable', 'UserController@datatable')->name('user/datatable')->middleware('role:A');
```

And finally the `index.blade.php` file where the `userTable` is located:

```
<table id="userTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" data-toggle = "table1_" style = "width: 100%;">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                  <th>E-Mail Address</th>
                  <th>User Type</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                  <th>E-Mail Address</th>
                  <th>User Type</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
```

I don't know what causes the error and how to fix it for now because it doesn't have any response data or other error/s that will give me a hint.

Comment: You are seeing the `Header` , click the `Preview` to get the error

Comment: @sta it says : Failed to load response data. Is it the code from the controller that causes this?

Comment: Open this on a new tab, and find the error

Comment: It redirects me back to the user.index page.